# A matrix whose column is a power of each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-rank

I'm wondering if a specific matrix is invertible or not. More specifically, let $a_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
3\\ 
4\\ 
5
\end{pmatrix}$. Consider a $5\times5$ matrix $A$ such that $A=[a_1, (a_1)^2, (a_1)^3, (a_1)^4, (a_1)^5]$, where this powers are element-wise powers.

So $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1&  1& 1 &1 \\ 
2 & 4 & 8 & 16 &32 \\ 
3 & 9 & 27 & 81 &243 \\ 
4 &  16&  64& 256 & 1024\\ 
5 &  25&  125& 625 & 3125
\end{pmatrix}$.

In this case, I know $A$ is invertible. For an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix A, where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} &\cdots  &(a_{1})^n 
\end{pmatrix}$, how can we tell A is invertible or not? All elements in $a_{1}$ are distinct.

Comment: I'm not sure about this becuase i have only studied till 3rd order matrices but a matrix is defined to be invertible if $|A|$ not equal to $0$. I believe a bit of induction can prove this easily

Comment: Also, you should all condition that no element is $a_1$ is $0$

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Yes, none of the elements in $a_1$ is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix will be invertible whenever the elements $a_i$ are all distinct and non-zero.  This follows from the invertibility of the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).  In particular, it suffices to note that your matrix can be written as the product $M = DV$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix
$$
D = \pmatrix{a_1\\&a_2\\ &&\ddots\\ &&& a_n}
$$
and $V$ is the Vandermonde matrix, as defined in the linked article.

Of course, if one of the $a_i$ is equal to zero, then the matrix will have a row of zeros and therefore fail to be invertible.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know there exist such a matrix and I suffered for a long time to prove that an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix is invertible. Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: Glad to help. Note that the linked article also gives some proofs for the described formula for the determinant which you might find interesting.